# Integrating Vue+Vite into an existing PHP project

Tags: php, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am experienced on PHP and Javascript and used them extensively up to now. I never used modern js frameworks like Vue, Angular or React and very new to this concept. And also have no experience with bundlers.

Now I want to try it and enter to the new world of modern web app development. I've started reading with Vue docs and liked it.

But I am not ready to develop a Single Page App from scratch. Instead I want to try it within an existing project (with PHP backend and ES6 frontend)

I've searched for such integrations but could not found any helping document.

I want to use:

- .vue SFC files
- Hot updates (HMR)
- Vite

**More info:**

The PHP framework I use have single index.php entry and virtual routing via htaccess.

Simple structure is like:

```
www/
├──.htaccess
├──index.php
├──Application/
├──public/
│   ├── js/
│   ├── css/
├──Modules/
│   ├──MyVueApp/
│   │   ├──Controllers/
│   │   ├──Views/
│   │   │   ├──index.phtml
│   │   ├──Model.php
│   │   ├── //and etc...
```

At location `http://localhost/en/MyVueApp` Backend framework renders a dynamic index page within a layout.

**Contents of index.phtml**

```
<?php
$this->layout->addCss('css/my-vue-app/main.css')
$this->layout->addJs('js/my-vue-app/main.js')
?>

<div id="app"><!-- vue app mounts here --></div>
```

How can I install and run Vite+Vue on this structure and how can I publish it for production ?

Comment: ask yourself why you even need php? once you bundle the SPA its can be run from apache or any other static file server, its a SPA after all, you won't need $this->layout->addCss and $this->layout->addJs etc, PHP's job would be simply a rest API, but then your ask yourself why put PHP in the mix when nodejs is js, and doesn't need additional tools, like, server, PHP installed, diff linters and package mangers etc etc.

Comment: The question was sipmlified to make it easy ro understand. Actual situation is more complicated. I am trying to integrate Vue into an existing project. I can not use an index.html file cause I have to use PHP frameworks layout engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just recently I've published **`vite-plugin-php`** a Vite plugin to use PHP-files as entry points for your application.
This helps me a lot with the development of smaller sites. You can use all the  usual tools like Tailwind, TypeScript etc. without any major hackarounds.

Have a look at:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-php

Answer (score 4):

The solution can be found at https://github.com/andrefelipe/vite-php-setup

Live Reload Plugin makes the job.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-live-reload